# Arduino I2C via USB Serial cable?

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, wire-library

An Arduino UNO is given.
I want to establish an I2C communication channel between Arduino UNO and a Linux Machine which have only USB ports available to communicate with peripherals. 
Currently I can communicate with Arduino board via USB Serial cable (TXD and RXD which are on pins D0 and D1).

My question is: is there any way to use those pins as SCL/SDA to communicate via I2C with Arduino Board?

I am thinking that the only way to accomplish this is to buy an USB to I2C Adapter and connect to A4 (SDA) and A5 (SCL); but maybe I'm wrong.

I have also seen that way: https://gist.github.com/kraftb/8c0bbcc35a9778608d74. Basically to use an intermediate Arduino board.

Comment: Why? I wonder ...

Comment: @LookAlterno Because it's faster?

Comment: The speed grades for I2C are: standard mode: 100 kbit/s; full speed: 400 kbit/s; fast mode: 1 mbit/s; high speed: 3,2 Mbit/s. USB 2.0 Hi-Speed is 480 Mbit/s (~57 MB/s). USB is faster.

Comment: What about Serial port speed? USB speed is not limited by Serial speed from Arduino UNO?

Comment: Because the Uno uses an *actual* UART between its main and USB chips, you'll only get high data rates over USB if you find a high baud rate that works for both.  On an actual Uno they are both closely related ATmegas running from comparable clock sources, so divider inaccuracies at least won't be an issue.

Comment: This seems like it might be an XY problem - do you really want I2C, or do you just want to move data faster?

Comment: I'm voting to close this abandoned question because it arises from a misconception

Answer (score 0):

With [SoftwareI2CLibrary](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/SoftwareI2CLibrary) you can specify other pins, I haven't tested it with RX and TX.

I would recommend the USB serial interface is fast (2M baud) in perspective to that we are discussing a Arduino with a speed of 16MHz.

Answer (score -1):

The Arduino contains a USB to UART adaptor (made from an ATMega16U2) which then connects to the UART pins 0/1. If you want a different protocol you will need a different adaptor that works with your desired protocol.

Comment: This may somewhat miss the point - even if you reprogram both chips on the Uno, you'd have to bit-bang I2C between them, which is certainly slower than using their hardware UARTs.  Now if you could do some surgery to connect their I2C pins it might be a different story.  But theoretically their UARTs can run faster than I2C's faster mode.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Personally I would use a direct USB connection to a suitable microcontroller. Especially as I now have my own modular USB stack for my favourite PIC32 microcontrollers...

Comment: This is a bit miss leading, an Arduino can have different USB to Serial IC chip.

Comment: A genuine Arduino made within the past few years has an ATMega16U2. If it doesn't then it isn't an Arduino. It's a clone, or a counterfeit device.

Comment: If you change your answer to a "Arduino UNO", then you are correct. And counterfeit? It is open hardware and the reality is that there is a lot of different "Arduino" USB-serial solutions out there.

Comment: Arduino is a brand. It is trademarked. While it is open source hardware the name isn't. Arduino Uno, Arduino Mega 2560, etc, are all made by Arduino and Arduino only. Or they have been counterfeited.

Comment: @Majenko, I have old Arduino originals with other USB-serial IC than the ATMega16U2!

Comment: Yes, **old** ones. Current ones have the ATMega16U2. I too have Uno R2 that has the 8U2. But the **current** version, the R3, that has been out years, uses the 16U2.

Comment: In case you hadn't noticed, the question specifically talks about Arduino UNO. Ergo the answer must be about the Arduino UNO. There are three classifications of "Arduino" device: Genuine (e.g., the Arduino UNO made in Italy), clones (devices *based on* the Arduino hardware but crucially *not called Arduino*) and counterfeit (devices that claim to be an Arduino UNO but aren't made by Arduino). The latter infringes the Arduino trademark and are actually illegal. Also they are usually of very inferior quality.